# Get specific column of specific row without loop in php

Tags: php

```
      $output         = QuerySelect($sqlCheckSameTeamLead, $selectBindings);

function QuerySelect($query, $bindings = NULL){
        global $connPDO;
        $statement = $connPDO->prepare($query);  //prepare statement
        $statement->execute($bindings); //execute Statment
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //return result in associative array
    }
```

I am looking for a way to get `$output` second row and specific column but without loop. I can loop through `$output`but i want to avoid it.

Comment: `$output[1]['column']`?

Comment: @Nick is correct. But you shouldn't do it this way anyway. It's very inefficient if you need only some of the rows. Always consider how much memory that $output will hold

Comment: I'm curious how's the loop way? Is something like this: `for($row = 0; $row < $count; $row++) if($row == 1) return ...`?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you dothat via your query
Example:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1, 1
```

Gets only the second row, then you can use SELECT clause to get the desired columns.